# human readable data file

Tags: matlab, file-io

Apart from csv file, which other options do I have to read and write human readable data files in matlab? The data consists of unique parameter value pairs (not necessarily hierarchical - see below).

My situation is this. I am currently using xml2struct to read a XML file, which is then transformed into a struct of parameters. Unfortunately, I cannot use this approach anymore as I intend to use Matlab coder, which does not support cell arrays or strrp etc.

Any feedback would be very much appreciated - especially something that is robust in terms of Matlab coder.

Comment: What is the problem with csv, or tab separated files etc? Furthermore this may be interesting for you: http://www.mathworks.nl/products/matlab-coder/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/coder/coderdemo_struct_array.html

Comment: The problem is that it would expand too much into horizontal direction (problem when you just have a text editor). Also alignment of parameter name and value not very clear ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also [write](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33381-jsonlab-a-toolbox-to-encodedecode-json-files-in-matlaboctave) a [Json](http://www.json.org/) file, it is structured and kind of human-readable. I have no idea on its compatibility with Matlab coder.

Comment: Thanks. JSON is great. Not sure if I hit the same problems as with xmltostruct. guess I have to try ...